# When is ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC combination useful?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I was using **WebForms** earlier, now I'm very satisfied with the **MVC**. But as for the many tutorials I have read the words from those articles that to combine MVC and WebForms may be useful sometimes, but they didn't reveal the essence in their tutorials/articles more specifically.

For e.g.:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575397/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-MVC-for

#### quote

*In fact the possibility of being able to mix both the styles is the best thing. We can use both these styles in a single application and get the best of both worlds.*

And the same words for the others tutorials, which I read. I can't see any concrete.

As for me, what strong sides I've noticed, when I've used WebForms:

- development style, which is more like to the desktop-development style, when I've first used WebForms, I feel like I was developing some `WinForms/WPF` application
- page life cycle gives not only big headaches but also a very good mechanism for controlling webpages events/render html code. Yes it's complex and hard to learn/understand, but when you have done it you may to develop a very powerful application. I have done such perversions, where I was imitating a desktop developing style (I have built smth similar to the html collector, which may free some html code and include/render another and it was looked like a manager which manipulating scenes for future rendering like in `WPF/Silverlight` development and I was able to manipulate 30 different html pages only in one page (which I think many developers prefer to divide into such amount of pages) with such a self-developed manager).

Why do I tell you these things? I see that you may think that I switched to another topic and changed the meaning of my question and make it meaningless.

No! It's not, I've just provide such an information, because I don't understand where are those needed/correct parts of combining those two techniques for the real practice.

These two techniques have different life cycles, they works on different patterns, they render their pages very differently, they are just very different.

I can't imagine how it could be combined.

Maybe I don't know something...

Please tell me your opinion about combining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is fresh MSDN Magazine [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198242.aspx) related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to fallback on traditional webforms if you rely on complex user controls specifically created with the webforms model in mind (needs viewstate etc).
MVC follows the HTTP protocol more closely while WebForms tries to abstract it away by creating an experience much more similar to that of WinForms.

Comment: sorry, but I don't find any suggestion from you about combing these two techniques :( the main question was about its combining, not comparing

Comment: I'm saying combine if you need legacy web forms functionality, but use MVC if you don't

Comment: ah.. I see, sorry for misunderstanding firstly :)